# Telerik MVC Grid: setting state of form checkbox to state of row checkbox for MVC application using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

A bit of a tough one i think. I have a telerik mvc grid that has a cell that is a checkbox. Its disabled, and i have a piece of jquery code that when a row is selected, fills some html boxes on the form based on what is in there. I have a checkbox that i need assigned, and i know its not as simple as `$('#checkbox').val(row.cells[13].innerHTML)`. I have to check the state using something to the effect of whats on this page :

http://jvance.com/blog/2009/07/14/GetValueOfCheckboxUsingJQueryToEnableButton.xhtml

but im not sure how to check the value with the telerik grid. Has anyone done this before or have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well i managed to find the answer. For future reference its this:

```
var checked = $(row.cells[13]).find(':checkbox').attr('checked');
```